# Directed colimit and homology

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am looking for a reference or a proof of the following fact:

Let $X_{1}\subset X_{2}\subset\dots $ be a sequence of (hausdorff) topological spaces indexed by natural numbers such that each   $X_{i}\subset X_{i+1}$ is a closed subspace for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$. We define $X=colim_{i\in \mathbb{N}}X_{i}$.

Then the $H_{m}(X,\mathbb{Z})=colim_{i\in \mathbb{N}}H_{m}(X_{i},\mathbb{Z})$ for any natural number $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Theorem on page 115 of Peter May's book [A concise course in algebraic topology](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf).

A discussion can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341832/when-will-homology-and-direct-limit-commute?rq=1).

Comment: @Thanks for the references, as far as I understand, your first reference does not answer explicitly my question. The discussion you linked, says something interesting. the condition for which it becomes true is : if any map $K\rightarrow X$  (K compact) factors through some $X_{i}$.  Is it true in the case of my question ?

Comment: The reference *does* in fact answer your question. And yes, it is true

Comment: @Max in the reference it is written "union of an expanding sequence of subspaces" what does it mean exactly ?

Comment: That it is the colimit of its subspaces

Comment: @Max I do believe that the condition "if any map $K\rightarrow X$ ($K$ compact) factors through some $X_{i}$"  is essential, it is not always verified. I do believe  that compact spaces are small with respect to closed inclusion of Hausdorff spaces but not small for arbitrary inclusions.

Comment: It is possible that May has some hidden assumptions that imply your condition, for instance if he is working with compactly generated spaces. He states : "From here on, we agree that all given spaces are to be compactly generated,
and we agree to redefine any construction on spaces by applying the functor k to
it". With this condition, you get the thing about compact spaces : the proof given here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584667/compact-subset-in-colimit-of-spaces) indeed works just as well

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf) is a reference, proposition 2.4.2 page 49.